# Java regex to parse a string with special chars and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I need a java regex to split the words from the following pattern.

The sentence will start with @ symbol and continue with 6 numerals and then @ symbol.
Then 9 numerals and then [ symbol
Then 6 numerals and @ symbol
Then 2 numerals

There may be space in between the special character and number

```
For example :

    @123456@ 123456789[ 123456@ 12

Here my output should be like :
     string1 = 123456
     string2 = 123456789
     string3 = 123456
     string4 = 12
```

The below regex is not spliting the words properly . Anyone help on this?

```
@[0-9]{6}@[0-9]{9}[[0-9]{6}@[0-9]{2}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why not use "\d+" to get all numerals....

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  1) Are you trying to test for valid input and/or 2) what are you trying to extract from the input.  Your "example" doesn't shed any light on the matter because you give a String which has spaces in it--which you do _not_ mention anything about.  If you want to parse the String such that the `'@'` symbol and `'['` symbols are separators then [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) will do that (or StringTokenizer or `String.split(...)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Capture Groups

You can match into capture groups:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^@(\\d{6})@ *(\\d{9})\\[ (\\d{6})@ (\\d{2})");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String firstGroup  = regexMatcher.group(1);
    // 123456
    String secondGroup = regexMatcher.group(2);
    // 123456789
    String thirdGroup  = regexMatcher.group(3);
    // 123456
    String fourthGroup = regexMatcher.group(4);
    // 12
}
```

Comment: Hi..firstGroup >>@123456 ..how to avoid the @ symbol. I want only the 123456.

Comment: @JavaUser If you study the regex a bit, everything matched between brackets is stored as a capturing group. In this case, just move the `@` and `[`s out of the brackets.

Comment: @Unihedron Thanks, I hadn't seen that he had added sample output—very helpful JavaUser, thanks, and let me know if this is working for you now.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `(...)` to incapsulate "capturing".

```
@([0-9]{6})@([0-9]{9})\[([0-9]{6})@([0-9]{2})
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex-pattern by which you want to split is: `[@\[]\s*`. This [overview](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex) will help to understand the pattern.
In Java it looks like follows:

```
String string = "@123456@ 123456789[ 123456@ 12";
String[] strings = string.split("[@\\[]\\s*");
```

The `strings` array will contain the desired output `[123456,123456789,123456,12]`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your pattern

```
    String s = "@123456@ 123456789[ 123456@ 12";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@(\\d{6})@\\s?(\\d{9})\\[\\s?(\\d{6})@\\s?(\\d{2})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
        System.out.println(m.group(4));
    }
```

Comment: Solution depends on what do you mean by words. Now I know what the author meant (code edited)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `String.split()`!

```
{
    String[] strArr = "@123456@ 123456789[ 123456@ 12".split("[@\\[] ?");
    string1 = strArr[0];
    string2 = strArr[1];
    string3 = strArr[2];
    string4 = strArr[3];
}
```

> [Online Demo](http://ideone.com/ZaixnQ) **STDOUT**:
>   123456
>   123456789
>   123456
>   12

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@[0-9]{6}@\s[0-9]{9}\[\s[0-9]{6}@ [0-9]{2}
```

You should quote the actual `[` and add the spaces you want.

See this [working example](http://regexr.com/397su).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the spaces, add them with the * quantity to have 0 to unlimited.
And make sure to escape the [

```
@[0-9]{6}@ *[0-9]{9}\[ *[0-9]{6}@ *[0-9]{2}
```

Works fine in the RegEx-Tester http://erik.eae.net/playground/regexp/regexp.html